# C++ template inheritance with pointer type

Tags: c++, templates

I have a template struct and I want that every pointer type instantiates the const version, to avoid having duplicate templates. This doesn't work, but it work with the char pointer. How can I make it work with any pointer?

```cpp
#include <iostream>

template<class T>
struct Foo {
  static void bar() {
    std::cout << __PRETTY_FUNCTION__ << std::endl;
  }
};

// Doesn't work
// template<class T>
// struct Foo<T*> : Foo<const T*> {};

// Works
template<>
struct Foo<char*> : Foo<const char*> {};

int main() {
  Foo<char*>::bar();
}
```

Comment: Neither of these two compiles on GCC: https://godbolt.org/z/sjrdYxro6 - Which compiler are you using where it "works"?

Answer (score 1):

You can do it if you extract a base class from `Foo`:

```
#include <iostream>

template<class T>
struct FooImpl {
  static void bar() {
    std::cout << __PRETTY_FUNCTION__ << std::endl;
  }
};

template<class T>
struct Foo : FooImpl<T> {};

template<class T>
struct Foo<T*> : FooImpl<const T*> {};

int main() {
    Foo<char*>::bar();
    Foo<const char*>::bar();
}
```

Unlike @Guillaume answer, this does not require C++20.

Answer (score 1):

Since `T` can also be `T const`, you are creating infinite inheritance, hence the incomplete type error.

Since `const T*` matches `T*` with `T` being `char const` for example, you makes the class inheriting from itself be inheriting from `Foo<T const*>`, which expands to `Foo<char const const*>` which collapses to `Foo<char const*>`.

Simply add a constraint and your code works as expected:

```
// Now works
template<class T> requires (not std::is_const_v<T>)
struct Foo<T*> : Foo<const T*> {};
```

[Live example](https://godbolt.org/z/9eqeqEKzE)